# Chromebook/chromebox IDE/compiler option?

Tags: ide, web

My daughter has a chromebox she uses for all her email/homework/etc.  We've started to get into making ADABOX projects and I was looking for best options for chromebook users.  I saw that codebender was shutting down.  And Chromeduino looks like it might have problems with libraries.  Currently I am looking to just set her up with a Raspberry Pi she can connect to with her chromebox and use it to connect to the Arduinos/Feathers, since I know she will need libraries and things from adafruit.  But I was hoping there might be newer options I haven't found yet.

Comment: Arduino Create?

Comment: @Majenko from what I can tell it does not have a way to connect USB to Chromebook like codebender.

Comment: Ah well. Maybe the pi is the best way. She'll learn Linux too then.